# Trying to exclude all files in a directory from DevOps to SonarCloud Fails

Tags: azure-devops, sonarcloud

I can't figure out what is wrong with this task in DevOps to exclude all files in the path:
**.AdminCenter/companyname.AdminCenter.FrontEnd/xyz/lib

```
- task: SonarCloudPrepare@1
  inputs:
    SonarCloud: 'SonarCloudTokenDigitalisering'
    organization: 'digitalisering'
    scannerMode: 'MSBuild'
    projectKey: '***************.AdminCenter'
    projectName: 'AdminCenter'
    extraProperties: |
      sonar.exclusions=**/lib/**/*,**/*.dll
      sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/**/coverage.opencover.xml
  sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=$(Agent.TempDirectory)/*.trx
```

`sonar.exclusions=**/lib/**/*` should do the trick, but all files are still visible in the Code-tab
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try specifying the full path to the *lib* folder in the `sonar.exclusions` property.

`sonar.exclusions=AdminCenter/companyname.AdminCenter.FrontEnd/xyz/lib/**/*,**/*.dll`

If there is `Test` in the name of the folders, it will be considered test files. You will need to add `sonar.test.exclusions` property. `sonar.test.exclusions=**/lib/**/*,**/*.dll`.

You can also try setting the `File Exclusions` in your [SonarQube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SonarQube) UI. See [this blog post](https://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2017/07/22/exclude-folders-from-sonarqube-analysis/).

[image]

Comment: www.codewrecks.com link is broken